# How to open a custom popup programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a simple android application which does search. I have a custom popup window to select filters.

I am now developing a homescreen app widget to that. The app widget is similar to that of Google Search Widget for android.

There is a filter which pops up, a search box (fake) and a search button(instead of google's voice button).

Everything is working great except for the popup.

When the filter button is clicked on a widget, i trigger a intent with an extra that indicates home button is clicked.

When the activity opens, i check for the extra and performClick() on the button that is supposed to open the popup. But that's not working. Any idea?

My code is something like this -

In the widget I have -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean(CALL_FROM_WIDGET, true);
bundle.putBoolean(HOME_BUTTON_CLICKED, true);
intent.putExtras(loginBundle);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

In the Activity I have -

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null && b.getBoolean(CMWidget.HOME_BUTTON_CLICKED)) {
home_button.performClick();
}
```

I have a onClickListener set something like this -

```
home_button = findViewById(R.id.home_button);
home_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

i have implemented onClick() here which pops up the custom popup menu. Popup menu has Quick Action Items.  

});
```

Comment: Could u post ur code? Without the code its difficult to find the problem.

Comment: I have the question updated with the code.

Comment: Buddy u have posted all the code but not the one which has problem.. How have u implemented custom pop up? It might have some problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was looking for this one which no one replied.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null && b.getBoolean(CMWidget.HOME_BUTTON_CLICKED)) {
findViewById(R.id.anchor_button).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showPopup();
            }
}
```